# How to quick to get everything from destructuring assignment?

Tags: javascript

For example, I have a object with server functions.

```
let funs = {
  fun1: () => { console.log('fun1') },
  fun2: () => { console.log('fun2') },
  fun3: () => { console.log('fun3') },
};
```

then I want to have quick way to use this function set.

```
class SampleClass {
  sampleFun() {
    {...funs} // anything similar to it?
    fun1();
  }
}
```

Comment: Not possible, because that would require dynamic variable names. There's `with`, but please don't use that

Comment: There is a option with `eval` but eval is not evil.

Comment: I think all answers are correct, but I'm actually looking for shortcut form; like what @CertainPerformance said, there is no way to have shortcut expression.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible.

I close alternative is calling that function, using the function `call` with `funs` as lexical context.

```js
let funs = {
  fun1: () => { console.log('fun1') },
  fun2: () => { console.log('fun2') },
  fun3: () => { console.log('fun3') },
};

class SampleClass {
  sampleFun() {    
    this.fun1();
    this.fun2();
  }
}

new SampleClass().sampleFun.call(funs);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pull the functions into the namespace of your instance with `Object.assign()`, then you could call with `this.fun1()`, etc...

```js
let funs = {
    fun1: () => { console.log('fun1') },
    fun2: () => { console.log('fun2') },
    fun3: () => { console.log('fun3') },
  };
  
class SampleClass {
  constructor(funs) {
    Object.assign(this, funs)
  }
  sampleFun() {
    this.fun1()
    this.fun2()
    this.fun3()
  }
}
let s = new SampleClass(funs)
s.sampleFun()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that. In other words you are asking for Dynamic variable names which are not possible without using `eval()`. Here is your code the names of function are in series you can call all using loop.

```js
let funs = {
    fun1: () => { console.log('fun1') },
    fun2: () => { console.log('fun2') },
    fun3: () => { console.log('fun3') },
  };
  
class SampleClass {
  constructor(funs) {
    Object.assign(this, funs)
  }
  sampleFun() {
    for(let i = 1;i<=3;i++){
      this[`fun${i}`]();
    
    }
  }
}
let s = new SampleClass(funs)
s.sampleFun()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think all answers are correct, but I'm actually looking for shortcut form; like what @CertainPerformance said, there is no way to have shortcut expression